# How do I view a PDF file saved in my document directory using Swift?

Tags: swift, pdf, uiviewcontroller

I've built an ordering app and have encoded the order sheet as a PDF that saves to the document directory.

I want to have a method to preview the PDF prior to sending it as an email and was hoping someone can give me some advice on how to load/preview the PDF and how to send it using `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PDFKit.amazing tool for PDF viewing https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit

```
import PDFKit

class TextPreviewController: BaseController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak private var pdfView: PDFView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        let fm = FileManager.default
    let docsurl = try! fm.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let myurl = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("Owl.jpg")
    guard let path = myurl,
        let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))else { return }
    pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
    pdfView.autoScales = true
    pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
    pdfView.document = pdfDocument
    }
            
}
```

you just need to put you link on PDF and it will be open.

Comment: This is great thank you. Silly question how do i put a link on the pdf? Sorry, I am new to this and appreciate your help

Comment: do you know the folder and the file name saved on phone? (You can find this in code where you try to save the file in phone memory)

Comment: I edited the code. you need to put a file name (instead "Owl.jpg") on your like ("Hello.pdf")

Comment: Great yes I do have the address from the device.  Thanks again.